# Reading HTML entities

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, html-entities, xml2

Using xml2 package in R converts HTML entities into Unicode characters:

```
xml2::read_html("<html> This is a dash &#8211;  <html>")
# {xml_document}
# <html>
# [1] <body><p> This is a dash \u2013  </p></body>
```

I would like to keep HTML entities because, if I later use pandoc to convert HTML to LaTeX, `\u2013` is removed, while `&#8211;` is properly converted to `--`.

How can I achieve this?

### Edit

I am on Linux R 3.6.1 - Package xml2 1.2.0

Comment: This doesn't happen on my work machine (Windows 10, R 3.6.1, xml2 1.2.0). I get `[1] <body><p> This is a dash –  </p></body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual solution, but a workaround:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8")
xml2::read_html("<html> This is a dash &#8211;  <html>")  
# {xml_document}
# <html>
# [1] <body><p> This is a dash –  </p></body>
```

Note, I still lose the HTML entity, but the output is correct and is consistent with Windows output (based on comments posted).

The fix only works if I run R in my terminal emulator. If I run R in Emacs, I keep getting `\u2013`.